# smoothly move a JButton component to mouse click position in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a little better than beginner level understanding of Java and I am having trouble with a student assignment. I had to turn a class (student.java) "into a button" - which I have done (that's why instead of creating a new instance of JButton, my code creates a new instance of "student").  I need to have the button relocate its position to wherever the user clicks the mouse.  I have successfully done that, so my assignment requirements have been met.
However, I would like to have the button move smoothly to the location of the mouse click, as opposed to abruptly jumping from the previous position to the new position.  Below is my code. The maths inside of the mouseClicked() method is what I have tried, but it has no effect on the motion of the button.

- null layout is required
- must use MouseListener (not ActionListener)
- button must be an instance of class student

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
public myJPanel(){
    super();
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.decode("#F5F2EB"));
    setVisible(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    Font f = new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.BOLD, 16);
    student btn = new student("First","Last", num, "");
    add(btn);
    btn.setBounds(100, 150, 400, 90);
    btn.setText(btn.getInfo());
    btn.setBackground(Color.decode("#89A690"));
    btn.setForeground(Color.decode("#F5F2EB"));
    btn.setOpaque(true);
    btn.setFont(f);
    btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 40, 20, 40));

    // move btn object
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();  //mouse click x position
        int y = e.getY();  //mouse click y position
        int px = btn.getX() - x;  //previous btn x position(to get distance between old / new position)
        int py = btn.getY() - y;  //previous btn y position(to get distance between old / new position)
        double speed = 5; //speed
        double ang = (float)Math.atan2(py, px) * 180 / Math.PI;  //angle
        x += Math.cos(ang * Math.PI/180) * speed;  //move to x
        y += Math.sin(ang * Math.PI/180) * speed;  //move to y
        btn.setLocation(x,y); //relocate button to new location
    }});
```

Comment: What does your "student" button look like?

Comment: It looks like a regular JButton.  student.java extends JButton. So when you create a new instance of student, it has the btn dimensions noted in the above code (btn.setBounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of animation concept in your code, simply updating the location will not move it smoothly. Changes you require

- remove setLocation() code from mouse listener
- a timer to trigger calculation and update of button position
- interpolation of current position given elapsed time, angle etc.

Example. Here I've calculated total distance, and then interpolated "distance so far" based on time and speed.

Also note use of Math.toDegrees() and Math.toRadians(), although you don't really need them at all unless you want to use ang as degrees elsewhere...

```
public class Foo {
    private static class Animate extends JPanel {
        private JButton btn;
        private int startX;
        private int startY;
        private long startTime;
        private double ang;
        private double distance;

        public Animate() {
            super();
            setLayout(null);
            btn = new JButton("Dr Horse");
            btn.setBounds(100, 150, 40, 10);
            add(btn);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    startX = btn.getX();
                    startY = btn.getY();
                    startTime = System.nanoTime();
                    int px = btn.getX() - e.getX();
                    int py = btn.getY() - e.getY();
                    distance = Math.sqrt(px * px + py * py);
                    ang = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(py, px));

                }
            });
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / 20, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    double duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e6;
                    int speed = 50;// pixels per second
                    double distanceSoFar = Math.min(speed * duration / 1000d, distance);
                    int x = startX - (int) (distanceSoFar * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(ang)));
                    int y = startY - (int) (distanceSoFar * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(ang)));
                    btn.setLocation(x, y);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Animate());
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much, Adam - this is perfect (it works). I tried using Timer but lost my way when I received the error stating it had to be attached to ActionListener  -  but I needed to use MouseListener so got confused -  now I get it.  I upvoted you but I'm a new user so, apparently, it won't show publicly ;)  Thanks again for your help and speedy response!

Comment: No worries, glad to help, if my answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting" it by clicking on the grey tick. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks

Comment: Done.  Thanks again!